# keyup and keydown are not synchronized?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, synchronization, jquery-events, jquery-1.8

I'm trying to build a complex WYSIWYG, and for this I want to create some actions after some keys are pressed.

For this I'm adding the jquery `keypress` and `keyup` listeners on a div with `contenteditable`. One of my actions make some changes on the HTML, and after this changes my cursor position should stay the same.

My problem that when I'm processing the `keyup` event, there is no relation between `keyup` and `keydown`.

The `keyup` events shouldn't be fired in a time relation.

If you start writing in the example bellow, you can see that there is no order between `keydown` and `keyup`.

If the key **A** was pressed after the key **B** the ´keyup` for **A** should be fired after the event for **B**.

```js
var result = document.getElementById('div-result');
function log(msg) {
  result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + '<br>' + msg;
}
$('#div-editable').keydown(function(e) {
  log('down:&nbsp;' + e.keyCode);
});
$('#div-editable').keyup(function(e) {
  log('up:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.keyCode);
});
log('Iniciando log...');
```

```css
div#div-editable {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #333333;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-editable" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

<div id="div-result"></div>
```

There is no way to synchronize these methods. In other words, when I'm processing `keyup`, `keydown` **SHOULD** wait.

Comment: I don't get what the issue is.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve using key down and up?

Comment: I have to break all wrote text into words. Something like `word1 word2 word3` should turn into `<word>word1</word> <word>word2</word> <word>word3</word>`.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Keydown and keyup occur in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keyup` and `keydown` are literally that. I can press and hold <kbd>a</kbd>, press <kbd>b</kbd> and then let go of <kbd>a</kbd>.

This will give you: keydown: a, keydown: b:, keyup: b, keyup: a.

You have to be able to deal with these events being *'out of order'*.

Comment: Ok. And how I deal with that? This is the question! There is no way to create any synchronization?

Comment: You mean track the cursor position? Do you _really_ need to know where the cursor is while `onkeyup/down` events are firing? You can always fetch the cursor position using the Selection/Range API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range

Comment: I believe you don't undestook my question. I know get the range and selection. I want to know there is a way to synchronize that events!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Victor I think that's very hard to do. When you press right-arrow for a while how do you know where the cursor is going to end up? I think the beast you can do is synchronize the cursor position on `keyup`.

Comment: @Ben please communicate that through the proper channels, don't leave that as a comment as it's not relevant to helping OP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to keep some state information about which keys are currently being pressed down so that you can ignore any duplicate events until it is depressed. E.g.,

```
var result = document.getElementById('div-result');
var pressed_keys = {};

function log(msg) {
    result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + '<br>' + msg;
}

$('#div-editable').keydown(function(e) {
    if (pressed_keys[e.keyCode]) {
        // Currently pressed, ignore.
        return;
    }

    // Mark key as pressed.
    pressed_keys[e.keyCode] = true;

    log('down:&nbsp;' + e.keyCode);
});

$('#div-editable').keyup(function(e) {
    log('up:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.keyCode);

    // Mark key has depressed.
    pressed_keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

log('Iniciando log...');
```